# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/userdetails' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: spring-boot, ionic-framework

I have create a REST service to authenticate and It was successful.

I have created another service and calling the service by passing token.

It's working fine in Postman.

[image]

I am trying to call it from Angular.

[image]

The login form working fine.

```js
loginURL: string = 'localhost:8080/authenticate';

this.http.post(this.loginURL, {
    username: 'headoffice',
    password: 'guest'
}).subscribe((successResp) => {
        resolve(successResp);
    },
    (errorResp) => {
        resolve(errorResp);
    }
);
```

But when I am calling the localhost:8080/api/auth/userdetails

```js
userDetailsURL: string = 'localhost:8080/api/auth/userdetails';
token: string = '.....';

this.http.post(this.userDetailsURL, null, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    })
}).subscribe((successResp) => {
        resolve(successResp);
    },
    (errorResp) => {
        resolve(errorResp);
    }
);
```

I am getting the error like

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/userdetails' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
zone-evergreen.js:2845 POST http://localhost:8080/api/auth/userdetails net::ERR_FAILED
```

This is the websecurityconfigurer

```java
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
     httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().anyRequest()
         .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
         .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
         .and().sessionManagement()
         .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
         .addFilterBefore(customJwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
 }
```

This is WebMvcConfigurer

```java
 public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
     registry.addMapping("/**")
         .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD", "TRACE", "CONNECT")
         .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
 }
```

Please help me out.

Why it's working in postman and not working in Angular.

What did I miss?

Comment: _“it's working in postman and not working in Angular”_ has close to zero relevance - Postman is not a browser, CORS restrictions do not apply to it in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

When using CORS with spring security you have to do one more step in your security configuration to make it work. It happens because the CORS must be processed first.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors#cors-with-spring-security

In your security configuration, you must call the cors before the rest of you logic

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.cors().and()...
}
```